# Insert font awsome icon in any shape in vis js

Tags: javascript, html, font-awesome, vis.js, bpmn.io

Is it possible to insert any font awsome icon in any other shape (i.e. box, diamond, circle) in vis js? i want to add shapes like [BPNM Gateways](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/bpmn/gateways) or [Gateways](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/2821/286/56997_gateway.html).
 If above is not possible, how/where i can modify the source code to full fill the requirement?
 Is there any way to add my customs shape to vis js?

Comment: It can be done using 'beforeDrawing' / 'afterDrawing' on network layout initilization

Answer (score -1):

Not sure but, as much I understand, you want this..

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
      <i class="fa fa-circle-thin plus-icon fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-plus plus-icon fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
```